# Consulta de Registros em Campos DATE por Mes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá!
Gostaria de um auxilio estou realizando consultas em uma tabela `VIAJEM` onde possuo 2 campos `IDA` E `CHEGADA`. Ambos do tipo `DATE`. Preciso consultar todos os registros de um determinado `MES`.

Ex. `ida = '2016-08-15' chegada= '2016-09-01'`. Apesar da chegada ser em setembro a consulta deve trazer todos os registros do mes de agosto que estao cadastrados.

```
SELECT * FROM viajem WHERE Month(ida) = $mes or Month(chegada)=$mes;
```

Tenho que capturar a variável via `$post`  e depois substituí-la na QUERY.

Comment: Faltou eu colocar o WHERE, mas a minha dificultade seria a data selecionanda no COMBO BOX para o a classe PHP conseguir colocar na query.

Comment: Clique em editar sua pergunta em vez de posta comentários. Faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Olá Apolonio, bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Para melhorar suas chances de obter uma resposta é sempre bom incluir um exemplo de código demonstrando o problema. Para mais informações de uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está confusa. Se for filtrar só o mês 8 para a ida e mês 8 para a volta vc de colocar na condição:

```
WHERE MONTH(ida) = $mes(valor inteiro) AND MONTH(chegada) $mes(valor inteiro)
```